# Enable legacy template in angular@4.0.0

Tags: angular

After upgrading to angular4 browser spits at me lots of warnings about deprecation of "template" (superseeded by "ng-template"). The problem will persist till the libraries I use will move on to new angular version. Can I in the meantime somehow silence this warnings? In changelog they written:

```
compiler: Add a enableLegacyTemplate option to support <template>
```

In the commit in tests I've seen following code:

```
providers: [{
  provide: CompilerConfig,
  useValue: new CompilerConfig({enableLegacyTemplate: false}),
}],
```

Where I should put this code? I've tried putting it in main app module, but it did not help. Do I have to do this for each of my modules? 
Is there another way to go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap function accepts compiler configuration, so you can add this option to it like this:

```
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(YourModule, {
    enableLegacyTemplate: false
});
```

For modules it is no longer working since 4.0.0. A bug maybe?

Comment: Yes. It was a bug https://github.com/angular/angular/commit/8ffa483bb6f1b52eb6893692d90b12415fcf8155